# NLP: Extracting domain specific Data from PDF Files

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp

NLP Problem:
I have pdf file which contain some important information that needs to be extracted. Some of them are in key value pairs. . For example, the pdf file contains the following information.

- Name : Mr. John Wick
- Toy purchased : Gun
- Price : £2,000
- Date: XYZ

However, not all the documents will have the same keys, for example in some docs it could be

- Price of Item : £4,000
- Current Date or Purchase Date: ABC
- Purchased Toy Etc.

What is the best way to extract this data ?

Comment: Have a look at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/ as it could be something that might be of use to you